# Two independent wifi routers, one subnet?

Tags: wireless-networking, router, wireless-router, wifi-configuration

I have a house in another province which I hardly stay in. I intend to have 2 independent wifi routers, one, with cable internet, which my ip cameras are connected to; the other one as a backup router (using a SIM card) with a built-in battery. Both will be on 24/7.

As I will connect my Wemos D1 mini, backed up by a supercapacitor, to the latter router and the wemos will run a sketch that keeps monitoring which cameras (which are connected to the main router) have disconnected, for whatever reasons, from the main router, and if so, send a notification to my phone. The wemos will also send notifications when my house has a power outage.

As the sketch running on Wemos will need to access the main router to sniff for the active known mac addresses of all the IP cameras, I understand that both routers must be on the same subnet. My question is, how to set up these two routers to give same-subnet IPs, but different IP address, to all the devices without interfering with each other and my wemos still can check the status of my IP cameras?

Comment: Set their DHCP ranges so they do not conflict, I'd guess. Also, what is a "sketch"?

Comment: thanks. They call the programming source code for these microprocessors a sketch.

Answer (score 0):

Both would be configured for 192.168.0
Router 1 for example would have a static IP of 192.168.0.1 and router 2 would have 192.168.0.2.
Both would use 255.255.255.0 or /24 as their subnet mask.

Then router 1 could have a dhcp range of 192.168.0.1 to 192.168.0.127
and router 2 could have 192.168.0.128 to 192.168.0.254

---

An alternative is to get a raspberry Pi 4 or similar to run an independent DHCP server and maybe DNS.

In this case you would disable DHCP server on both routers and they would get there IP address from the Pi 3/4.

Obviously the setup would be a bit more complex.
Then you would have the raspberry Pi route your traffic to either router 1 or router 2.

You could setup a ping test, say once an hour, and then if it fails it switches to router 2.

Comment: Thanks. If possible, I would not add another device into the picture because I seldom stay at the house.
Would two routers set up as described above to avoid duplicate ip addresses still allows my Wemos to ping the other devices connected to the other router?

Comment: @bthoven  Here's the problem, routing the packets to the correct gateway router 1 or router 2.  If the device has a router 1 ip it will have a router 1 gateway and all traffic will route there.  If router 1 goes down the devices won't ask router 2 for an IP until the dhcp lease time is up and that could be days.  Maybe you adjust the lease time in routers, and maybe you can't.

Comment: @bthoven Maybe you can do something with your Wemos D1 mini.  You say your going to sniff traffic with it, so I assume you have a USB type c network dongle because there is no other way to attach it to the network I can see.

Comment: @bthoven  So it is networking capable so I would make your Wemos D1 a dhcp server and gateway and then it can decide which router your traffic goes to.

Comment: Thanks all. I may let my one wemos alternately connect to my 2 routers and check the status of the cameras associated with each router, alternately.